# c++ macro output type based on the macro function argument

Tags: c++, macros, variable-types

I am trying to define my variable type based on a boolean variable comes into my macro function, but I get compiler error.

```
#define myImageType(depthImage) ((depthImage)==0 ? int : double)

int main()
{
bool inMilimeter = true;
myImageType(inMilimeter) pixelIntensity;
}
```

Comment: The ternary comparison operator isn't handled by the preprocessor. Forget about that approach. A template maybe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use [`std::conditional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional).

Since the type must be decided at compile-time, the boolean must also be a constant expression:

```
#include <type_traits>

#define myImageType(depthImage) \
std::conditional<depthImage, int, double>::type

int main() {
    constexpr bool inMilimeter = true;
    myImageType(inMilimeter) pixelIntensity;
}
```